# Does TimeCamp powerup for Trello require a paid plan?

Tags: trello, integration

I'm a bit confused about the various plans of TimeCamp webapp.

According to their [website](https://www.timecamp.com/en/pricing/), integrations are not included in the basic free plan, they are listed only in the paid ones.

Anyway, it is not clear to me if the TimeCamp powerup that one can enable from inside a Trello board is considered to be such an integration or not.

The documentation pages on [Trello](http://info.trello.com/power-ups/timecamp) or [TimeCamp](https://www.timecamp.com/en/trello-power-up-time-tracker/) websites about this subject are not very clear about this.

Is there somebody here that uses both services and can help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

No, TimeCamp power up for Trello doesn't require a paid plan, because, as it's mentioned on Trello pricing plans page, a free plan includes one power up per board.